# error OAuthException "message": "mailbox requires the read_mailbox extended permission."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am getting this error while trying to access Facebook Graph api mailbox

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/inbox?access_token=<access_token> 


"error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "mailbox requires the read_mailbox extended permission."
```

The access token is valid.. But any hints on the permissions and where I am going wrong..
First, on logging in to Fb, it gives me a code and then access_token

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant your application the `read_mailbox` permission.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

Information on how you do that can be found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: @Brain: It is authenticating the user.. (letting me enter my username and pwd) but it is not asking for any allow permissions... It gives me an access token though

Comment: You need to specify which permissions you want in your oauth request, as the guide I linked to above shows you.

Comment: @Brain: Once the user is successfully authenticated, the OAuth Dialog should prompt the user to authorize the app. In my case it is not doing so...Directly, it goes on to get the access_token.. Any hints.. Is it related to IIS and virtual directory

Comment: the permissions are specified using the scope parameter, in case you're using Facebook Javascript SDK. [See](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking)

Answer (score 3):

This is outdated, with the latest release(current version 2.6), you can't access private messages.

Answer (score 0):

At this time it is not possible to use the instagram API without an application authorization. The tutorials that teach how to use it through a token generated by the graph api do not work. For the application, you will first need to send some documents from your company, wait for validation, and then send advanced resource requests