# Facebook messages in the windows application C#

Tags: c#, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error OAuthException “message”: “mailbox requires the read_mailbox extended permission.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767584/error-oauthexception-message-mailbox-requires-the-read-mailbox-extended-perm)

I am developing a windows application in which i have to read the facebook messages and show them in my application. 
For that..
First i have given this "read_mailbox" permission on my facebook app after that when i am trying to get messages by this code

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(FacebookOAuthResult.AccessToken);
var res = fb.Get("/me/inbox");
```

it is throwing an exception

> (OAuthException) (#298) Reading mailbox messages requires the extended permission read_mailbox

Please help me ho to resolve this. What i am missing here?

Answer is:

Just need to pass read_mailbox in the parameter also.

like

```
       string[] extendedPermissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "read_mailbox" };

       if (extendedPermissions != null && extendedPermissions.Length > 0)
        {
            var scope = new StringBuilder();
            scope.Append(string.Join(",", extendedPermissions));
            parameters["scope"] = scope.ToString();
        }

        this.loginUrl = oauth.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
```

Comment: It will be better for You if you publish your answer as Answer (bellow), and accept it ;).